# R data.table: Cannot mix positives and negatives

Tags: r, data.table

I want to subtract an integer (e.g., `20`) from every row of a specific column (e.g., `dist` column) in the `data.table` below:

```
require(data.table)
CARS <- data.table(cars)
head(CARS)
   speed dist
1:     4    2
2:     4   10
3:     7    4
4:     7   22
5:     8   16
6:     9   10
> CARS[CARS$dist - 20,]
Error in `[.data.table`(CARS, CARS$dist - 20, ) : 
  Item 1 of i is -18 and item 4 is 2. Cannot mix positives and negatives.
```

It looks like `data.table` does not like mixing positive and negative numbers.  The class of my object `CARS` is:

```
class(CARS)
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

In terms of benchmarking, I want my code to run as fast as possible.  As such, it would be nice to see if there are perhaps a few alternative possible solutions, benchmarked against each other for performance speed.

Comment: CARS$dist = CARS$dist - 1 ???

Comment: Fixed... thanks for the edit...

Comment: It is not what @astrosyam suggested.

Comment: `data.table` structure is `DT[i, j, by]`. `i` is used for subsetting by condition, `j` is used for running different operations on the variables or selecting columns, `by` is for grouping. You are trying to operate on the columns in `i` instead of in `j`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the result to the `i` variable of `[.data.table`. You can't mix negative (dropping rows) with positive values in here.

You get a similar error with a data.frame

```
 x <- data.frame(x=1:5)
 x[-1:2]
# Error in `[.default`(x, -1:2) : 
#  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

y <- data.table(x=1:5)
y[-1:2,]
# Error in `[.data.table`(y, -1:2, ) : 
#  Item 1 of i is -1 and item 3 is 1. Cannot mix positives and negatives.
```

Your question suggests you want to pass the argument to `j` (and using `data.table` you don't need `CARS$`prefix

```
CARS[ ,dist - 20]
```

Comment: Just adding for OP that  what `i` was looking for in their approach was _row indices_; `-18` means _exclude the 18th row_ and `2` means _include the 2nd row_. Mixing exclusion and inclusion rules is not allowed (understandably).

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to replace all negative numbers with 0, a simple solution would be:

```
CARS[(dist - 20)<=0,dist:=0]

CARS[(dist - 20)>0,dist:dist-20]
```